# What is Safety Play?

Tags: pool

I found this rule

> 2-8 Safety Play Prior to any shot except the break, you may declare a
>   safety. On a safety, your inning ends after the shot regardless of
>   whether you pocket any ball. If you do not declare a safety and you
>   pocket a ball on an obvious shot, your inning continues and you must
>   shoot again. A safety must meet the requirements of Rule 1.19, Legal
>   Shot, or it is a foul. (AR p. 77, 103)

at this site: http://www.playcsipool.com/uploads/7/3/5/9/7359673/2014-2015_official_rules_of_csi.pdf

I'm not sure I understand the rule. Why would you ever call "safety" instead of calling a random ball in pocket on the off chance that you make it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because after a safety, you're hoping to leave the balls in such a situation that it's difficult for your opponent to pot anything, so they make a mistake which opens up the table. The last thing that you want to happen is that you leave the cue ball (e.g.) tight on the rail behind a couple of other balls and then *you have to take another shot*.